# Why is there a minimum Ic for a optocoupler?

Tags: opto-isolator

I got confused when I saw this on a HCPL-181 optocoupler datasheet.

[image]

You can get the datasheet here: [HCPL-181 datasheet](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0774EN).

So what would happen if the collector current goes below 2.5mA? (In fact I am using the optocoupler for a 50uA output current.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stated Collector Current rating in the datasheet refers to minimum and maximum **guaranteed current** that the transistor collector will pass, for a current of 5 mA through the LED. The variation accounts for manufacturing differences between pieces, not for an individual part.

This does not prevent the application from passing less current by external limiting of the current.

The datasheet information, and the corresponding behavior, are similar to conventional BJTs, other than that the corresponding base current is not specified.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it.1.what do you mean by "guaranteed current"? 2.2.5mA to 30mA manufacturing differences?Isn't it too large?

Comment: @user1423693 Guaranteed --> If there were no external resistance or other current limiting in the C-E circuit loop, that much current would be allowed to flow. Unlike conventional BJTs which are manufactured (or binned after manufacture) to tighter tolerances, an optocoupler with a phototransistor is less stringently binned, variances can be pretty high as it does not affect the intended application significantly. The application is as you describe in the question, something where the actual current will be limited externally, and the transistor acts as a switch, not a linear-zone amplifier.